# Print function prints twice a field from a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am using the `print` function to print a field from a class from another python module and it prints the field twice.

I have two modules:

**main.py:**

```
from statics import RiskyCars

class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# init
RiskyCars()
print(RiskyCars.risky_cars[0].name)
```

**statics.py:**

```
class RiskyCars:

    @staticmethod
    def __init__():
        from main import Car
        RiskyCars.risky_cars = []
        RiskyCars.risky_cars.append(Car("car1"))
```

When I run `main.py` it print twice:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/myuser/PycharmProjects/Project1/main.py
car1
car1
```

But if I put breakpoint before the `print` function:

```
# main.py
# init
RiskyCars()     <--- break point
```

and then run manually from the terminal:

```
print(RiskyCars.risky_cars[0].name)
```

it prints only one time.

Why it happens ?

Comment: A couple of things strike me as odd: `__init__()` is marked static and you `import` from main. Basically: do neither of these things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python renames the primary script you run `main` for you as `__main__`. What happens is that you run `main` (called `__main__`) which runs `RiskyCars.__init__` which in turn imports `main` (called `main`). Hence the script `main` runs twice.

The solution is to rewrite `main.py` to be

```
from statics import RiskyCars

if __name__ == '__main__':  # only execute if run as main script
    # init
    risky_car_1 = RiskyCars()  # lets at least pretend this is sensible
    print(RiskyCars.risky_cars[0].name)
```

`statics.py` to

```
from cars import Car

class RiskyCars:
    risky_cars = []
    def __init__(self):
        RiskyCars.risky_cars.append(Car("car1"))
```

and make a new file called `cars.py`

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Comment: Thanks.
I can't move the imports outside of the function `__init__` because it will cause a bidirectional importing: `statics.py` imports from `main.py` which imports from `statics.py` and so on.. and then I won't be able to use `RiskyCars()` in `main.py`.  
The probably best way to avoid this, is like you and @Aran-Fey mentioned, separate the code - put Car in a different file.

Comment: I'm glad the interpreter bans this if you put the import in the normal place. That should have been a warning though ;)